# Issues in displaying a flash message in my HTML page

Tags: python, html, flash-message

I just started to learn python some months ago...
I would like to display an message when there is no result for a query in my Query page (html). I am using python and flask. The code that I tried did not display any message.
My id.html code is (I included the code outside the search form):

```
<div class="flashes">
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    {{ message }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And my python code is:

```
@app.route('/id')
def id():
    params={}
    params['entryname']='Search ID'
    idn=request.args.get('idn')
    sql=text('select * from DATA where info LIKE :id')
    words=engine.execute(sql,id=idn).fetchall()
    params['objs']=words
    if params['objs']==0:
        flash('No Results')
    return render_template('id.html', **params)
```

I also tried this just for testing and did not work

```
if params['objs']>0:
        flash('Results')
```

I am not sure what is wrong in my code, the query search is working, but no message...

Answer (score 0):

> *"I also tried this just for testing and did not work"*
>
> ```
> if params['objs']>0:
>         flash('Results')
> ```

I don't use Python but it sounds like you're trying to check the **size** to make sure it contains something? If yes, then possibly this logic might help you :

Either use **`is_empty`** or the **`len`** properties :

```
if is_empty(params)==True:
        flash('No Results')


if len(params)==0:
        flash('No Results')
```

Also if you wanted *bigger-than* then write as :  `if len(params) > 0: flash('Results')`

Comment: This one worked (in the sense that I did not get any error): if len(params) > 0: flash('Results'),  but no message is been shown